# Unable to test Flutter app on iPhone due to certificate issue

Tags: xcode, flutter

I built a Flutter app using Android Studio.  Works fine on iPhone simulator.
When I go to test on my iPhone however by opening up workspace on Xcode and running it with my iPhone connected to my laptop, I get this error:

The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.

I'm at a loss at what to do here.  I am using a free apple developer account.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need a new certificate (development certificate) installed on your mac's keychain.

First go to the the apple developer console, then Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles => Certificates => Add Certificate **(Plus Button)** => Apple Developer Certificate.

[image]

In order to generate a new certificate you will need to export a new certificate request from your Mac's Keychain Assistant, in order to be able to sign new applications.
To do this: Go to the **Keychain Assistant App => Keychain Access => Certificate Assistant => Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority**.
Go through the steps to generate this new certificate request and Save it to your Desktop.

Go back to your Browser, where you are trying to create a developer certificate through the Apple Portal, and upload the generated Certificate Request file.

[image]

A new certificate will be created, then download this certificate, and click on the downloaded file, and your MacOS (Depending on any Security Policy) will ask you to type your password to add the new certificate to your keychain.

This certificate will now be used by your Mac to sign all developer applications.
Please note that for production, you will also need another certificate (depending on whether you are uploading to the App Store or distributing via AdHoc).

Once you've done all this, go to the App's Provisioning profile on your Mac Account (via your Browser), then select your provisioning profile of your app, then click **Edit**. There should be a certificates section, please choose all of them to sign your app.

After this is all done, go to Xcode, then Manually download the provisioning profiles to your device => Clean => Rebuild => Deploy via Flutter. **Please also make sure to remove any revoked (expired) certificates from your keychain (to clean up the memory bank).**

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I'm stuck at your first step.  As I'm using a free version of Apple developer account, when I tried to go to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section it says "This resource is only for developers enrolled in a developer program or members of an organization’s team in a developer program."  Any thoughts??

Comment: You need a developer account to do this then. Apple I believe had decommisioned free provisioning services, so you can't deploy to a physical device unless you have a paid account

Comment: I beleive it costs 99 usd a year

Comment: I have a better idea. When you say "The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application", it means that somebody else has given you this developer certificate and you installed it on your keychain. Could you perhaps ask, whomever generated the certificate for you, to create another one, export it from their keychain, and then send it to you, so that you can install it on your machine? That way you will need your own apple developer account for development purposes.

Comment: However, if you are using a new device, which does not currently exist on the dev account's device list, you will need to send them your new device UUID, which can be found from the device manager on Xcode. Send it to them, they will register the device, and manage the certificate for you.

Comment: Apple doesn't require a paying developer membership to test on devices (https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)...  I remember I was able to test on my iPhone for free when I made an app using Xcode.  That's I guess where my certificate is from originally.  Now that I'm making a Flutter app from Android Studio IDE, this issue is happening.  So I tried deleting a provisioning profile, deleted all certificates etc... but still having this issue...  :(